# fputcsv does not work with large arrays

Tags: php, csv

I'm using fputcsv to (obviously) create a csv file of a table in an application. I simply post  a 2d array of data to:

```
function formatoutput(&$vals, $key){
    foreach($vals AS $row=>&$cell){
        $cell = str_replace('"', '""', $cell); 
        $cell = str_replace(array("\n",','), '', $cell); 
    }
}

function outputCSV($array) {
    $outstream = fopen("php://output", "w");
    function __outputCSV(&$vals, $key, $filehandler) {
        fputcsv($filehandler, $vals);
    }
    array_walk($array, "formatoutput");
    array_walk($array, "__outputCSV", $outstream);
    fclose($outstream);
}

outputCSV(unserialize($_POST['data']));
```

so, for each line in the array, it appends it to the csv file. Well, this works fine until I pass in an array with around 500 or more lines.

Is there a size limit when using this function? The documentation doesn't mention anything. Or is there a PHP setting that would limit the size?

There is this question here: [is there a file size limit when creating a csv file using php and mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11249850/is-there-a-file-size-limit-when-creating-a-csv-file-using-php-and-mysql)

Which basically asks the same thing, but even though there is a marked answer, it doesn't really explain any possible solutions. It simply states:

"Sounds like a problem with your environment settings - not with the code or a limitation of the technologies."

Comment: What are your php.ini settings? In particular, what about memory_limit?

Comment: You don't need to do ANY of that `formatoutput` stuff. fputcsv already does that for you. essentially you're double-encoding your output. once via your function, and once via fputcsv.

Comment: Quite possibly your problem is the copy-on-change of your functions; you're passing your array to outputCSV by value, but changing it within your array walks.... so that's doubling memory usage.... fputcsv() doesn't have any memory limit, but your code duplication does

Answer (score 1):

PHP loads variables like these into memory.  And every script has a maximum amount of memory it is allowed to use, based on your php.ini settings.

Also, when variables are copied, they can take up double the space in memory. The source memory, and the destination memory.  I'm not sure the internals of fputcsv, but it's possible that the entire array is being converted to a csv "object" internally, then written out to file.

So, remember that you're possibly doubling your memory usage any time you copy.

In the very least, check your "memory_limit" in your php.ini.  If you need to increase it for one script in particular, then you can set it in your script with:

```
ini_set('memory_limit','16M');
```